# Speed up volume change Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

How can I speed up volume change when I'm using volume control keys? Mine are Fn + UpArrow, Fn + DownArrow.

The bar on the top left appears but the speed of volume change is too slow for me. How can I speed it up?

Comment: May be Ctrl or shift keys work.

Comment: @Biswa I have already tried this :(

Comment: Also there is a volume control in taskbar. Click on it and change the slide to control volume.

Comment: @Biswa I would like to do it with a keyboard, it's faster and sometimes you don't have a mouse on a laptop.

Comment: I'm aware of a way to achieve this in Ubuntu, but I don't think it's possible on Windows without a third-party hotkey modifier. According to [TechJunkie](https://www.techjunkie.com/adjust-audio-hotkeys-windows/), you can use a program called "3RVX" to achieve a result similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok then some autohotkey script may work.

Comment: @Candid Moon _Max_ have you found a better solution than just repeat delay?

Comment: @Julime unfortunately no, it was a long time ago, since then I have used AutoHotkey program to do various things but not with sound, though, I believe it has the ability to do this, so you might find some script that creates hotkeys for fast volume change. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=47784 - you may find there simple examples and more complex ones as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since this uses the keyboard, it depends on the key delay and keyboard repetition rate. In *Keyboard Properties*, decrease delay and increase repetition speed.
[image: Keyboard Properties]

Test this setting afterwards in an editing program, e.g. Notepad, to see if it's acceptable.

Comment: It does work, vote up. But I have already had my settings on maximum. Maybe it's possible to do it with some kind of bash script to change the settings.